# setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) doesn't show TextView

Tags: android

I have the following Layout in `res/layout/main.xml` with the second `TextView` hidden

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="world"
              android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this Android activity, which should display the second `TextView`

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        View tv2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

But when the activity is displayed, only the first `TextView` is shown.

So, what is wrong here? How can I make the second `TextView` visible
programmatically?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, setVisibility is defined in the super class of TextView.

Comment: @Blackbelt ohhhh okay sir .I never knew that .Thanks both of you

Comment: @Blackbelt Sir ,I have a question .Sir which one is best  .Using super class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the solution is embarrassingly simple, it took me quite some
time to figure this out.

The reason for the "invisible" element is the default orientation of
[`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html).
Right at the beginning it says

> **Class Overview**
>   ... The default orientation is horizontal.

Both `TextView`s have a width of `match_parent`, which means the first
TextView already occupies the whole width of the parent. Since I
forgot to set the `orientation` explicitly, the second TextView is
layed out to the right and is thus off the screen.

Setting the `orientation` to `vertical` fixes this issue and makes the
second `TextView` visible

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- ... -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: LinearLayout `orientation` plays a vital role